# How to convert a DataFrame with repeated indices into a MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    i  j  n
1   1  2  #
2   1  3  #
3   1  5  #
4   2  1  #
5   2  2  #
6   2  4  #
7   3  5  #
8   3  6  #
```

to a MultiIndex DataFrame like this:

```
      n
1  2  #
   3  #
   5  #
2  1  #
   2  #
   4  #
3  5  #
   6  #
```

I don't want to go row by row and inserting into a new DataFrame and I'm sure that there's a quicker way anyway.

Comment: Did you try using `set_index`?

Comment: df.set_index(['i','j'])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I initially misunderstood the documentation, the solution was quite trivial: `df.set_index(['i', 'j'])` results in the desired effect.